# Django + Ajax | File Upload | Server doesn't recognise Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to implement file upload using `ajax with Django` but facing some problem.

When the user tries to upload the files after selecting the file and submitting  the form, then as per my understanding , an ajax request should be send to the server using `POST` method ,but in my case a `POST` request is being made to the server, but the server is not able to identify it as an ajax request and browser is redirected to `http://<server>:<port>/upload/` and the contents on this page are as follows.

```
{"status": "error", "result": "Something went wrong.Try Again !!"}
```

Django Version: 1.6.2

Python Version: 2.7.5

Also, testing on Django Development Server.

**views.py**

```
def upload(request):
        logging.info('Inside upload view')
        response_data = {}
        if request.is_ajax():
                logging.info('Is_AJAX() returned True')
                form = UploaderForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

                if form.is_valid():
                        logging.info('Uploaded Data Validated')
                        upload = Upload( upload=request.FILES['upload'] )
                        upload.name = request.FILES['upload'].name
                        upload.save()
                        logging.info('Uploaded Data Saved in Database and link is %s' % upload.upload)

                        response_data['status'] = "success"
                        response_data['result'] = "Your file has been uploaded !!"
                        response_data['fileLink'] = "/%s" % upload.upload

                        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")

        response_data['status'] = "error"
        response_data['result'] = "Something went wrong.Try Again !!"

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type='application/json')
```

**Template**

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
<input id="fileInput" class="input-file" name="upload" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Post Images/Files" />
</form>
```

**Javascript 1:**

```
$('#uploadForm').submit(function(){

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
                url: '/upload/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
        });
        return false;
});
```

**Javascript 2**

```
var options = {
      url: '/upload/',
      type: "POST",
       error: function(response) {
               alert('Something went Wrong. Try Again');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if ( response.status == 'success' ) {
              alert('success');
             }
        }
};

$('#uploadForm').ajaxSubmit(options);
```

**Question:**

1) Why is Django not able to  recognize the ajax request and value of `request.is_ajax()` is always `False`.

2) Even if the server doesn't recognize ajax request why is my browser getting redirected to another page ?

There is another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742215/django-jquery-form-no-ajax-request) but with no result.

Comment: Are you using a plugin for sending the file through ajax? because if not, that might be the problem.

Comment: Also - can you check the headers of the request being sent and share the details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that javascript code block

```
$('#uploadForm').submit(function(){

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
            url: '/upload/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
    });
    return false;
});
```

loaded after your **uploadForm** html form in DOM on page. In your case seems you trying to bind submit handler with form element which not yet loaded so when you click, it send simple **POST** request.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me.  You need a [jquery.form.js](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

```
$("#uploadForm").submit(function(event) {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        url:'{% url upload_file %}',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            console.log("An error occurred while uploading your file!");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Here's the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload) with answers.

Comment: Hi, I don't know why it still doesn't work for me.
in javascript 2 in the question , I am using `jquery.form.js`.I tried your code but still getting the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

1) *why is_ajax() not working?*
Have you included the JQuery form plugin (`jquery.form.js`) ? `ajaxSubmit()` needs that plugin.

Take a look at http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

If it's already done, you might take a look at the `HTTPRequest` object

Django Documentation says `HttpRequest.is_ajax()`
Returns True if the request was made via an `XMLHttpRequest`. And if you are using some javascript libraries to make the ajax request, you dont have to bother about this matter. Still you can verify "`HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`" header to see if Django received an `XMLHttpRequest` or not.

2) Why page redirects?

As I said above, JQuery form plugin is needed for handling the ajax request and its call back. Also, for ajaxSubmit() you need to override the $(#uploadForm).submit()

```
 $('#uploadForm').submit( function (){
     $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
 return false;
 });
```

Hope this was helpful :)